# data.table rbindlist column of lists

Tags: r, data.table

I want to transform a nested list to a data.table but I get this error:

```
library(data.table)
res = list(list(a=1, b=2, c=list(1,2,3,4,5)), list(a=2, b=3, c=list(1,2,3,4,5)))
rbindlist(res)
Error in rbindlist(res) : 
  Column 3 of item 1 is length 5, inconsistent with first column of that item which is length 1. rbind/rbindlist doesn't recycle as it already expects each item to be a uniform list, data.frame or data.table
```

My result should look like this:

```
data.table(a=c(1,2), b=c(2,3), c=list(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(1,2,3,4,5)))
   a b         c
1: 1 2 1,2,3,4,5
2: 2 3 1,2,3,4,5
```

I there a way to transform this list? It should work without knowing the column names beforehand.

Comment: what type do you want column `c` to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is easy. But your input must be formatted as the following:

```
library(data.table)
res = list(list(a=1, b=2, c=list(c(1,2,3,4,5))), list(a=2, b=3, c=list(c(1,2,3,4,5))))
rbindlist(res)
```

You can transform your input with the following code

```
res = lapply(res, function(x) 
{ 
  x[[3]] <- list(unlist(x[[3]]))
  return(x)
})
```

Comment: If `res` is very long, you can avoid typing `list` for each element of `res` by using `res <- lapply(res, function(x){x[['c']] <- list(x[['c']]); x})`

Comment: Huh? I wouldn't have expected this to work (see my answer), but it seems it does! The only weird thing is that as soon as you change `list(a=....)` to `data.frame(a=...)`, it breaks again

Comment: How can I transform my input to the correct one? I don´t know beforehand which column is a sublist. I think I need to find every sublist and transform it...

Comment: I edited my answer. But if you don't know which column is list this is another question not asked in the current question.

Comment: You can do it with a nested lapply `res <- lapply(res, function(x) lapply(x, function(x2) if(is.list(x2)) list(x2) else x2))`

Answer (score 3):

Generally, R wants a column of a `data.frame` or `data.table` to be like a vector, meaning all single values. And rbindlist expects a list of `data.frames`, or things that can be treated as/converted to `data.frames`. So the reason your code fails is because it first tries to transform your input into 2 data.frames, for which the third column seems longer then the first and second.

But it is possible, you need to force R to construct 2 data.frames with each just one row. So we need the value of c to be just length-one, which we can do by making it a list with one element: a vector of length 5. And then we need to tell R it needs to really treat it "AsIs", and not convert it to something of length 5. For that, we have the function `I` which does nothing more then mark its input as "AsIs"

```
res <- list(data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=I(list(c(1,2,3,4,5)))),
            data.frame(a=2, b=3, c=I(list(c(1,2,3,4,5)))))
res2 <- rbindlist(res)
```

The `data.frame` calls are not even necessary, it also works with `list`. But generally, I think not relying on hoe other functions must first convert your input works best.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my answer. I was too fast writing it down.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to first process every sublist and convert it to achieve your example output, like so

```
library(data.table)

res = list(list(a=1, b=2, c=list(1,2,3,4,5)), list(a=2, b=3, c=list(1,2,3,4,5)))

DTlist <- lapply(res, function(row_){
    lapply(row_, function(col_){
        if(class(col_) == 'list'){ 
          list(unlist(col_))
        }else{
          col_
        }
      })
})

rbindlist(DTlist)
```

The result would be

```
   a b         c
1: 1 2 1,2,3,4,5
2: 2 3 1,2,3,4,5
```

Sorry post is edited, bc I didnt recognize what the OP is trying to do initially. This also works, if the OP doesnt know which the sublist column is.

Comment: You converted to `character`. I don't think it is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I didnt recognize what the OP is trying to do initially, updated my post to achive the goal, before seeing ur answer